# How to correctly add local Swift Package to Xcode 15 project to see and use its content?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I would like to create my first Swift Package to reuse code in different projects. Creating the Package was no problem. However, when adding as dependency to another project, I can neither see nor use the package content.

**The package:**
[image: Package config]
[image: Dummy class in Package]

**Package in project:**
[image]
[image]

As one can seen in the 3rd image, the package seems to be added correctly. Just as some other third-party package. However, while one can extend the third-party package within the project navigator and see its content, `MyPackage` cannot be extended and thus does not show any content. It is also not possible to `import MyPackage` or use its classes.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have the package open on 1 Xcode Window/Project at a time.

Close all Xcode windows then open the project.

You can edit the package from the project.

Comment: That really solved the problem, thank you very much! Is this a Xcode feature or just very, very bad design / UX?

Comment: @AndreiHerford I assume it is to prevent the package from going out of sync in other open windows but I am not sure.

Comment: Properly. However, it is no problem to open and edit any (Swift) file in two Xcode windows. I do not see the difference with packages. Anyway, it is poor design. Obviously Xcode knows that the package is edited elsewhere (does not show its content) so it should be no problem to show a proper hint/info.

Comment: Agreed my thought process was in the resolving/updating the package. If another window is changing the package at what point to the changes get pushed to the project? At every key stroke? Every save? But I agree with some something found be better.

Comment: This is another thing I need to figure out: How to use versioning with local packages? With a package on GitHub I can specify which version to be used locally in my project. Xcode loads the files from the corresponding commit and not the latest files. Isn't the same possible with local packages? But this is something for another SO question if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @AndreiHerford, I have never tried with local packages. My guess is that it isn't supported but I would check the documentation.